# Glitch when loading ARKit scene second time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I have a simple Unity scene (**Scene-1**) and a scene with **ARKit**.

I can switch between the scenes using `SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName")`

When I switch from Scene-1 to ARKit scene everything is fine.
But if after that I switch back to Scene-1 and once again to ARKit scene - the ARKit scene doesn't work, looks like it stuck. I see a frozen image from the camera, though all buttons work.

Why is it happening, and is there any way to load a scene with ARKit more than ones?

Comment: Maybe there are some GameObjects in your ARKit scene that Don't destroy on load. Then when you go to your ARKit scene for the second time those GameObjects will exist twice. Which might cause some errors. Check in your editor while you run your application to see if you see "DontDestroyOnLoad" in your hierarchy

Comment: @Shogunivar Thank you for the idea, looks like there is nothing like that in the ARKit scene. However, in the Scene-1 I use Vuforia, and it creates TextureBufferCamera and its child TextureBufferMesh which are under "DontDestroyOnLoad". Can it be the problem? This component is being generated by Vuforia in play mode, so I don't know how to make it destroyable. This component won't appear if I will disable the ARCamera Vuforia prefab... should I somehow disable-reenable it before switching between the scenes?

Comment: if its a camera it might try to use that camera instead of the main camera from the arkit scene, that might be the reason why its freezing

Comment: @Shogunivar Might be, thank you! How can I make it "destroyable" in this case?...

Comment: dontdestroyonload just means it wont be destroyed when loading a new scene. You should still be able to use GameObject.Destroy(GameObject.Find("thecamera").gameObject)

Comment: @Shogunivar Here you can see the screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919796/dontdestroyonload-how-to-destroy

Comment: @Shogunivar So I should destroy the object before loading the new scene, or destroy it after loading it? Strange that when I load ARKit scene I don't see this "DontDestroyOnLoad" component in the hierarchy.

Comment: That's because it's called from the code in the camera. You can just destroy it before loading the new scene and it should be fine. I shouldve probably linked this earlier but read up on this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: @Shogunivar Thank you, this hopefully may be a solution... I created a function for destroying these objects and assigned it to a button. When I click this button in Unity it works: these objects disappear and I see a frozen image from the camera instead of a live stream. But when I try it on my iPhone nothing happens. May it be so that this function doesn't work with iOS build?